# paymentQueue - transaction fail

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, in-app-purchase

I am building an app with In-App Purchases. The app has 6 products for sale (all consumable).

The app is able to recognize the products (from itunes connect) available for purchase using the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    //Apple Store
    appleStoreProducts = [productID, product5ID, product25ID, product100ID, product500ID, product1000ID]
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    self.getProductInfo()
}

func getProductInfo() {
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

        for product in appleStoreProducts {
         let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(objects: product) as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
        }
    } else {
        // Tell user that In-App Purchase is disabled in settings

        print("In-App Purchase is disabled in settings")
    }
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

    var products = response.products

    if (products.count != 0) {
        let newProduct = products[0]
        switch newProduct.localizedTitle {
        case "DOLLAR":
            product = newProduct
        case "five dollars":
            product2 = newProduct
        case "twenty five":
            product3 = newProduct
        case "one hundred dollars":
            product4 = newProduct
        case "thousand dollars":
            product5 = newProduct
        default:
            print("none of the above")
        }

        print("titile : \(newProduct.localizedTitle) \n description: \(newProduct.localizedDescription)")
    }
    else {
        print("Product not found")
    }

    let invalids = response.invalidProductIdentifiers

    for product in invalids {
        print("Product not found: \(product)")
    }
}
```

Then you can click a button to make the purchase of one of the items, for example:

```
  @IBAction func productOne(_ sender: Any) {
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product!)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
}
```

My PROBLEM appears next, when the paymentQueue method is called:

```
  func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {

        switch transaction.transactionState {

        case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased:
        //  self.pointsBought()
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

        case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:
             SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            print("transaction failed")
        default:
            print("ESTDO:  \(transaction.transactionState)")
            break
        }

    }
}
```

This method is called twice when I click once the button. The first time the transactionState is neither "purchased" or "failed", so it calls the default option. The second time the result is "failed". However, I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Relevant information: 
I am using an iOS device (iphone 6) to run the app
I am using the developer account (of the app) in my iphone

Comment: "I am using the developer account (of the app) in my iphone" There's a special in-app purchase test account that you set up at iTunes connect. That is the account you must use. Sign out of iCloud so that you're not using your normal account.

Comment: The reeason the first it neither purchased or failed is because it is trying to do an old transaction. You need to add the other methods to account for this "paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error)" "paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue)". You also need to add the case above for "restore" and "defer"

Comment: I am not sure why the 2nd time it is failed, though.

Comment: @matt gives an extremely valuable hint: Make sure you're signed out of iTunes & App Store on you device before you do a purchase so that you have to enter the credentials of your test account when your app / App Store asks for it. Ergo, do NOT sign in to your test account from iOS Settings > iTunes & App Store or things will/may not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are failing to cover every case. You need to cover all of them, and you need to call `finishTransaction` for certain cases. This is the format of a correct `updatedTransactions` method:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for t in transactions {
        switch t.transactionState {
        case .purchasing, .deferred: break // do nothing
        case .purchased, .restored:
            let p = t.payment
            if p.productIdentifier == whatever {
                // ... do stuff ...
                queue.finishTransaction(t)
            }
        case .failed:
            queue.finishTransaction(t)
        }
    }
}
```